# Excel: any formula to calculate percentage growth over time

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula

I have 36 columns represents as many months, the values in these columns show the number of IT resource units used by a bunch of applications in my workplace (each app is a row). I want to calculate the percentage growth for each application.

I realise I can simply use an equation:

> (m36 - m1) / m1 * 100

However, if m1 or m36 represent an atypical value, this will skew the result. Rather I want a more consistent average. Is there a formula in excel to do this or does anyone know a better equation?

Comment: If you _know_ the endpoints are outliers I suggest you look at the interim development points `m2/m1`, `m3/m2`, etc. Is there a more stable pattern there? If so, you can select a reasonable average monthly growth factor _mf_ and scale it up to whatever timeframe you need by taking e.g. _(mf^36 -1) * 100_ for expected 36 month percentage growth.

Comment: If you are concerned about volatility in the result (and maybe you should), check by computing, say, _[(m36/m1)/(mf^36)]-1_. Is it 10%? 20%? You can reasonably pad expected growth by some fraction of this amount. The fraction should represent how likely you believe the abberation will occur in the period of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to the log-domain (so that you should get a straight line, outliers notwithstanding), and then apply [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).

Comment: Hi Oli. I'm actually using the FORECAST function in some other columns to predict growth in raw numbers (e.g. one number each for months 37-48). I believe this uses some form of linear regression. However, what I want here is a single percentage number: like what would be given from the formula in my first post, but accounting for skewed values.

Comment: @user1249196: You are looking for a best fit curve through your points.  Transforming the data and then performing linear regression is one way to achieve that.